# Very odd NullPointerException

Tags: swing, nullpointerexception, label

So in the process of making an ATM system I will have to ask the user if they wish to create a new account. That meant that the title of the ATM (located at the top) will have to change from "Login" to "Account Creation" or somesuch. So on the button press the text of the JLabel title needs to change. The problem is that when I press the button new account, all that happens is that the terminal window pops up indicating a NullPointerException at the following line:

```
title.setText("Create New Account");
```

From what I remember, this means that the object "title" is null. The problem is that it shouldn't be null, I am absolutely sure that I established it and I can't think of a reason why it is suddenly returning an error like this for me.

Here is the related code:

```
public class AccountSystem extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    public static Account currentuser = new Account(); //This is so that the methods know which account is currently logged in so they can perform operations on it.
    public static int count=0;
    public static Account acc[] = new Account[1000];
    public static String parts[] = new String[3];
    private JButton login, logout, createacc, deposit1, deposit2, withdraw1, withdraw2, transfer1, transfer2, nevermind;
    private JPanel optionson, optionsoff, loginarea, mainarea, titlecard, depositscreen, withdrawscreen, transferscreen, newaccountscreen;
    private JTextField username, password, transfer, depositarea, withdrawarea, retypearea;
    private JLabel userprompt, depositprompt, withdrawpromt, balancedisp, passwordprompt, mainmessage, title;
    private String newuser, newpass, newpassconfirm;
    BorderLayout borderlayout;
    GridLayout gridlayout;
    public AccountSystem()
    {
        borderlayout = new BorderLayout();
        borderlayout.setHgap(5);
        borderlayout.setVgap(5);
        //Establishing our buttons here.
        JButton login = new JButton("Login");
        login.addActionListener(this);
        JButton createacc = new JButton("New Account");
        createacc.addActionListener(this);
        JButton withdraw2 = new JButton("Withdraw");
        JButton transfer2 = new JButton("Transfer");
        //Establishing our panels here.
        JPanel optionson = new JPanel();
        JPanel optionsoff = new JPanel();
        JPanel loginarea = new JPanel();
        JPanel titlecard = new JPanel();
        //Establishing our JLabel here.
        JLabel userprompt = new JLabel("Username: ");
        JLabel passwordprompt = new JLabel("Password: ");
        JLabel title = new JLabel("LOGIN");
        //Establishing our textfields here.
        JTextField username = new JTextField(20);
        JTextField password = new JTextField(20);
        JTextField transfer = new JTextField(20);
        JTextField withdrawarea = new JTextField(20);
        mainscreen(getContentPane());
        //Building the GUI here.
        titlecard.setSize(500,50);
        titlecard.setLocation (0,0);
        loginarea.setSize(300,450);
        loginarea.setLocation(0,50);
        optionsoff.setSize(150,450);
        optionsoff.setLocation(300,50);
        titlecard.add(title);
        loginarea.add(userprompt);
        loginarea.add(username);
        loginarea.add(passwordprompt);
        loginarea.add(password);
        loginarea.add(login);
        loginarea.add(createacc);
        getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        getContentPane().add(titlecard);
        getContentPane().add(loginarea);
        getContentPane().add(optionsoff);
    }


public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) 
{
    if ((e.getActionCommand()).equals("Login"))
    {
        login();
    }
    else if ((e.getActionCommand()).equals("New Account"))
    {
        title.setText("Create New Account");
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can someone explain me why I'm getting this error in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8344989/can-someone-explain-me-why-im-getting-this-error-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You define the title variable as a class variable:

```
private JLabel userprompt, ....,  title;
```

and as a local variable:

```
JLabel title = new JLabel("LOGIN");
```

The title.setText() method is access the class variable which is null. Change:

```
//JLabel title = new JLabel("LOGIN");    
title = new JLabel("LOGIN");
```

You will need to do this for all the variable that you want to treat as a class variable.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you have declared, the `JLabel title` as an instance variable, you are still creating a new JLabel title in the constructor's local scope (remember that those are two different entities):

`JLabel title = new JLabel("LOGIN");`

And when the event handler (actionPerformed method) is called, you are actually accessing the ivar.

Which (if you recall) never was allocated.

So you can employ one of two choices:

Either instantiate the actual ivar title

```
title = new JLabel("LOGIN");
```

Or set the reference of local title variable to the ivar title.

```
JLabel title = new JLabel("LOGIN");
this.title = title;
```